# Handle Position Update in "real-time"

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

How long, in real life, is equivalent to 1 second of Veins Handle Position Update?

In the file omnet.ini I defined the simulation times and the handle position update as 100s and 1s, respectively. However, I'm not sure how much this would be worth in real life, since simulation time and real time don't add up.